# Ошибка импорта, при разделении файлов по папкам

Tags: python

Пытаюсь изменить структуру в папке gui, однако наталкиваюсь на ошибку импорта. Честно сказать не понимаю почему. Может вы мне подскажете, что я делаю неправильно? python 3.10.1

[image: struct]

modal содержит **init**.py

```
from .add_user_window import open_add_user_window
from .anticaptcha_window import open_anticaptcha_window
from .captcha_window import open_captcha_window
from .input_window import open_input_window
from .select_graph_window import open_select_graph_window
from .update_user_window import open_update_user_window
```

Появляется следующая ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\yom\Desktop\euraziareconcistah\vkbotpackage\vkapifastbot\app\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from gui import main_window
  File "C:\Users\yom\Desktop\euraziareconcistah\vkbotpackage\vkapifastbot\app\gui\main_window.py", line 5, in <module>
    from modal import open_add_user_window
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'modal'
```

Код импорта внутри main_window.py

```
from modal import open_add_user_window
from modal import open_anticaptcha_window
from modes import open_manual_mode_window
from modes import open_multi_mode_window
```

Comment: Если модуль model находится внутри модуля gui, то значит `from gui.modal`

Comment: Да, я уже понял свою оплошность... Благодарю за ответ!

Comment: Для того, чтоб по файлам, по  файлам проехать,
Надо раньше, надо раньше по папкам пройти!